# Continuous function on a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f: F \to \mathbb R$ be defined in a closed set $F \subset \mathbb R$. Show that $f$ is continuous if and only if for all $c \in \mathbb R$, the sets $E[f \le c]=\{x \in F; f(x) \le c\}$ and $E[f \ge c]=\{x \in F; f(x) \ge c\}$ are closed.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: One direction is very easy. For the other, assume that the sets $E[f\le c]$ and $E[f\ge c]$ for $c\in\Bbb R$ are closed. Then the sets $\{x\in F:f(x)>c\}$ and $\{x\in F:f(x)<c\}$ are relatively open in the subspace topology on $F$ for each $c\in\Bbb R$. This implies that if $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$, then

$$\{x\in F:a<f(x)<b\}=\{x\in F:x>a\}\cap\{x\in F:x<b\}$$

is open. Use this to show that $f$ must be continuous.

Comment: but maybe the function isn't defined for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @lechuza: Doesn’t matter: the sets that I defined are relatively open in $F$. I’ll modify the hint slightly to make that explicit.